# How can I graph using tikz a curve like \frac{1}{sqrt{1-x^2}}?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would appreciate it if someone could help me graph the function `\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}`.

Comment: Hello. This could help: [How can I make a graph of a function?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47594/how-can-i-make-a-graph-of-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are! 
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\f(#1){1/sqrt(1-(#1)^2)}
\draw[->] (-2,0)--(2,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-.5)--(0,3) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[dashed] (-1,-.5)--(-1,3) (1,-.5)--(1,3);

\draw[blue,smooth] plot[domain=-.93:.93,samples=200] (\x,{\f(\x)});

\path
(1,0) node[below right]{1}
(-1,0) node[below left]{-1}
(0,1) node[below right]{1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using the `pgfplots` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
  unit vector ratio = {1 1},
  grid = none,
  tick style = {black},
  % x axis
  xmin = -2, xmax = 3,
  axis x line = middle, 
  x axis line style = -{Stealth}, 
  xlabel = $x$, 
  xlabel style = {below},
  xtick = {-1, ..., 2},
  xticklabels = {}, 
  extra x ticks = {1},
  % y axis
  ymin = -2, ymax = 6,
  axis y line = middle, 
  y axis line style = -{Stealth}, 
  ylabel = $y$, 
  ylabel style = {left}, 
  ytick = {-1, ..., 5}, 
  yticklabels = {},
  extra y ticks = {1}
]
\addplot[domain = -0.99 : 0.99, samples = 1000] {1 / sqrt(1 - x^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It takes some time to compile due to the large number of samples chosen.

[image: Output of the MWE]